# Flex loadStyleDeclarations Error 2035 on Firefox

Tags: css, apache-flex, firefox, load

I'm loading a stylesheet from a swf into another swf via this call:

```
private var styleSheetURL:String  = "commonsStyles.swf";
private var dispatcher:IEventDispatcher;


dispatcher= StyleManager.loadStyleDeclarations( styleSheetURL + "?" + Application.application.parameters.myparam);
```

It works fine in a ll browsers except for Firefox 4.0.1, and even then its inconsistent across all tests machines. I get Error #2035 . That is URL Unknown error , which doesn't make sense because it works on IE so the loaded .swf must be present. I checked to see if there were any missing assets inside the css and I didn't find any but its a large css file so I could have missed something. Any ideas?

Comment: 1. Try specifying absolute URL. 2. Try loading it one more time on error - your network may be unstable.

Comment: Well its in the same directory as the parent swf and absolute URL would be tough because the URL changes based on whether its a dev, QA or production environment. I will try loading again though...

Comment: I'm still testing solutions, however, you can get the absolute URL dynamically by calling:   var urlPath:String = ExternalInterface.call("window.location.href.toString");

Comment: Update: Neither solution worked. The odd thing is it only happens in one test environment with Firefox, baffling...

Comment: Try adding this to Firefox bug tracker - https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/ , I've searched and seems that there are no such bugs yet.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to point to the Firefox Connection Settings. Try changing "Automatic Proxy Configuration URL" to Manual Proxy Configuration.